# RxJava: dynamically create Observables and send the final resut as Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am using RxJava in which I want to dynamically create a number of Observables based on some condition. Once I'm done with creating, I want to do some processing on the different values returned by the observables and then send as a single Observable to which I can subscribe on. Here is how my code is :

```
List<String> valueList = .... 

List<Observable<String>> listOfObservables = new ArrayList<Observable<String>>();

for(int i =; i <valueList.size(); i++){
        listOfObservables.add(new SomeClass.doOperation(valueList(i)));
        // SomeClass.doOperation will return an Observable<String>
    }

return Observable.merge(listOfObservables);
```

But here , I want to do some operation on the values emitted by different Observables in the `listOfObservable` and finally return it as a single `Observable<String>`

Like in `Observable.zip()` , I can do this like

```
return Observable.zip(observable1, observable2, (string1, string2) -> {
            // joining final string here
            return string1 + string2;
```

But I know the number of arguments here. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `zip` overload [that takes a variable number of arguments](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip(java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN)), it has a signature of

```
<R> Observable<R> zip(Iterable<? extends Observable<?>> ws,
                      FuncN<? extends R> zipFunction)
```

Example usage:

```
List<String> valueList = .... 

return Observable.from(valueList)
    .map(string -> SomeClass.doOperationThatReturnsObservable(string))
    .toList()
    .flatMap(listOfObs -> Observable.zip(listOfObs, (Object[] results) -> {
       // do something with the strings in the array.
       return Arrays.stream(results)
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }));
```

Comment: can you please explain more ? like how can I get the individual strings to do the operations ?

Comment: I've added an example usage. Keep in mind that if you don't care about order, maybe `merge` then `reduce` will be simpler.